# Añadir un array a un objeto desde el Main

Tags: java

Os explico tengo un clase materiales y luego tengo un array de partes de trabajo que entre otros atributos tiene el array de materiales.
La idea es la siguiente yo en el main creo un parte de trabajo y le doy valores en el case 1 a todo los atributos del parte de trabajo menos los materiales en el case 2 añado los materiales a un parte de trabajo para ello tengo un atributo que busca por nombre de cliente y fecha de parte un parte y a ese que ha hallado la idea es añadir los objetos materiales que he creado en el case 2 cada vez que pulse para el case 2 creo un objeto materiales y lo debería añadir al arraylisto que he buscado por año y nombre de cliente.

Os pongo el código del main porque no me va a dejar poner el código de las otras clases (tengo clase empresa con un arraylist de PartesDeTrabajo una clase Partedetrabajo que tienes entre otros atributos un arraylist de materiales y una clase materiales que tiene tipo de material y cantidad) si queréis ver otra clase que no sea el main decirlo y os lo paso no se que mostraros de código

```
 Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion; // Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

    while (!salir) {
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("1. Anadir un nuevo parte de trabajo");
        System.out.println("2. Añadir material al parte");
        System.out.println("3. Eliminar una carta");
        System.out.println("4. Listar  todas las cartas");
        System.out.println("5. Listar  todas las cartas nuevas");
        System.out.println("6. Listar  todas las cartas segunda mano");
        System.out.println("7. Buscar la carta mas cara");
        System.out.println("8. Buscar la carta mas barata");
        System.out.println("9. Buscar la carta mas antigua");
        System.out.println("10. Salir");
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("Elija una de las opciones");

        opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                String aux = "";
                String aux1 = null;
                String aux2 = "";
                char aux3 = ' ';
                String aux4 = null;
                double aux5 = 0;
                String aux6 = "";
                ParteDeTrabajo p = new ParteDeTrabajo();


                System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: ");
                aux = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha del parte en el formato (año-mes-dia): ");
                aux1 = entrada.nextLine();
                LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(aux1);
                System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del trabajador: ");
                aux2 = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Introduzca el estado de la reparacion: ");
                aux3 = entrada.nextLine().charAt(0);
                System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha de la reparacion: ");
                aux4 = entrada.nextLine();
                LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse(aux4);
                System.out.println("Introduzca los minutos de la reparacion: ");
                aux5 = Double.parseDouble(entrada.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Introduzca la descripcion del arreglo: ");
                aux6 =  entrada.nextLine();

                p.setNombreCliente(aux);
                p.setEstado(aux3);
                p.setNombreTrabajador(aux2);
                p.setTiempoReparacion(aux5);
                p.setFechaReparacion(localDate1);
                p.setFechaParte(localDate);
                e.aniadirParte(p);

                break;
            case 2:
                String aux7 ="";
                double aux8= 0;
                String aux9 = "";
                String aux10 ="";
                System.out.println("Introduzca la cantidad de material: ");
                aux8 = Double.parseDouble(entrada.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Introduzca el material usado: ");
                aux7 =  entrada.nextLine();
                 System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: ");
                aux9 =  entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha del parte: ");
                aux10 = entrada.nextLine();
                LocalDate localDate2 = LocalDate.parse(aux10);
                Material m = new Material();
                e.buscarPorFechaYCliente(aux9, localDate2);
                p.aniadirMateriales(p1)
                break;
```

Esta es la clase parte de trabajo

```
public class ParteDeTrabajo implements Comparable {

private String nombreCliente;
private LocalDate fechaParte;
private String nombreTrabajador;
private char estado;
private LocalDate fechaReparacion;
private double tiempoReparacion;
private String descripcionArreglo;
private List<Material> materiales;

public String getNombreCliente() {
    return nombreCliente;
}

public void setNombreCliente(String nombreCliente) {
    this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
}

public LocalDate getFechaParte() {
    return fechaParte;
}

public void setFechaParte(LocalDate fechaParte) {
    this.fechaParte = fechaParte;
}

public String getNombreTrabajador() {
    return nombreTrabajador;
}

public void setNombreTrabajador(String nombreTrabajador) {
    this.nombreTrabajador = nombreTrabajador;
}

public char getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(char estado) {
    if (this.estado == 'p' || this.estado == 'r') {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

}

public LocalDate getFechaReparacion() {
    return fechaReparacion;
}

public void setFechaReparacion(LocalDate fechaReparacion) {
    this.fechaReparacion = fechaReparacion;
}

public double getTiempoReparacion() {
    return tiempoReparacion;
}

public void setTiempoReparacion(double tiempoReparacion) {
    if (this.tiempoReparacion >= 0) {
        this.tiempoReparacion = tiempoReparacion;
    }
}

public String getDescripcionArreglo() {
    return descripcionArreglo;
}

public void setDescripcionArreglo(String descripcionArreglo) {
    this.descripcionArreglo = descripcionArreglo;
}

public List<Material> getMateriales() {
    return materiales;
}

public void setMateriales(List<Material> materiales) {
    this.materiales = materiales;
}

public ParteDeTrabajo(String nombreCliente, LocalDate fechaParte, String nombreTrabajador, char estado, LocalDate fechaReparacion, double tiempoReparacion, String descripcionArreglo, List<Material> materiales) {
    this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
    this.fechaParte = fechaParte;
    this.nombreTrabajador = nombreTrabajador;
    setEstado(estado);
    this.fechaReparacion = fechaReparacion;
    setTiempoReparacion(tiempoReparacion);
    this.descripcionArreglo = descripcionArreglo;
    this.materiales = materiales;
}

public ParteDeTrabajo() {
    this.nombreCliente = "";
    this.fechaParte = null;
    this.nombreTrabajador = "";
    this.estado = 'p';
    this.fechaReparacion = null;
    this.tiempoReparacion = 0;
    this.descripcionArreglo = "";
    this.materiales = new ArrayList<Material>();
}

public String aniadirMateriales(Material a) {
    materiales.add(a);
    return "material introducidos";
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String str = "";
    str += "Parte de trabajo" + "\n";
    str += "fecha del parte: " + fechaParte + "\n  nombre del cliente: " + nombreCliente + "\n  Atendido por: " + nombreTrabajador
            + "\n  estado del parter: " + estado + "\n fecha de reparacion: " + fechaReparacion + "\n se ha tardado: " + tiempoReparacion
            + "minutos \n ";
    for (Material m : materiales) {
        str += m.toString();
    }

    return str;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    ParteDeTrabajo p = (ParteDeTrabajo) o;
    if (this.getFechaParte().isAfter(p.getFechaParte())) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (this.getFechaParte().equals(p.getFechaParte())) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}}
```

Muchísimas gracias con esto espero terminar el trabajo que estoy haciendo y entregarlo.

Comment: Hola Carlos, la próxima vez dedícale más tiempo a plantear tu pregunta. No está nada claro lo que quires preguntar ni lo que has intentado para conseguirlo. De todas maneras he intentado contestarte, espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

En general no es buena práctica poner nombres genéricos a las variables, intenta que sean descriptivos de lo que hacen. En tu ejemplo estás haciendo muchas asignaciones innecesarias que hacen tu código más largo y difícil de seguir. Te demuestro lo que quiero decir:

```
switch (opcion) {
        case 1:

            ParteDeTrabajo parteTrabajo = new ParteDeTrabajo();

            System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: ");
            parteTrabajo.setNombreCliente(entrada.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha del parte en el formato (año-mes-dia): ");
            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(entrada.nextLine());
            parteTrabajo.setFechaParte(localDate);

            System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del trabajador: ");
            parteTrabajo.setNombreTrabajador(entrada.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Introduzca el estado de la reparacion: ");
            parteTrabajo.setEstado(entrada.nextLine().charAt(0));

            System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha de la reparacion: ");
            LocalDate localDate1 = LocalDate.parse(entrada.nextLine());
            parteTrabajo.setFechaReparacion(localDate1);

            System.out.println("Introduzca los minutos de la reparacion: ");
            parteTrabajo.setTiempoReparacion(Double.parseDouble(entrada.nextLine()));

            System.out.println("Introduzca la descripcion del arreglo: ");
            String description =  entrada.nextLine();

            e.aniadirParte(p);

            break;
```

Ahora contestando a tu pregunta o más bien a lo que interpreto que quieres preguntar. Para asignarle los materiales a un parte de trabajo, tu método `buscarPorFechaYCliente()` debería estar devolviendo una instancia de `ParteDeTrabajo` en ese caso lo único que tendrías que hacer es añadir el material que tu llamas m a esa instancia. Algo así:

```
List<Material> materiales = new Arraylist<>();
materiales.add(m);
ParteDeTrabajo unParteDeTrabajo = e.buscarPorFechaYCliente(aux9, localDate2);
unParteDeTrabajo.setMateriales(materiales);
```

Comment: Lo de las variables me ha venido de lujo no sabia hacerlo asi, la respuesta a mi pregunta no es eso. La idea es que en un Parte de trabajo que yo ya he creado  busco el parte donde quiero añadir el array de materiales y lo meto. No se esplicarlo mejor